# Introductory texts in abstract algebra, and game theory taking non-standard approaches

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, self-learning, game-theory

I like to see subjects from different angles. For example in linear algebra I'm reading through Axler's text (which takes a proof based approach for math students), but I'm also checking out a text on linear algebra in comp sci.

I'm wondering whether I could do something similar for my class on abstract algebra. We're using a text by Dan Saracino which is, I am told, very similar to the Dummit and Foote text on algebra (I've heard that Dummit is more popular, so I mentioned it as a point of reference). Are there any texts which would show me abstract algebra in a different light? Maybe a text on a geometric approach to abstract algebra, or a text on abstract algebra as applied to physics?

I'd also be interested in ideas for texts to complement my other classes. I've been thinking about checking out a book on differential equations to go with my class in classical mechanics, and maybe a book on game theory in economics to complement my comp sci game theory class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aluffi "Algebra: Chapter 0" with emphasis on the perspective of catagory theory.

[http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Chapter-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847813](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847813)